# Limpieza de indices en Google Datastore

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, google-datastore

Tengo una aplicación en [google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) utilizando [google-datastore](/questions/tagged/google-datastore), mientras la desarrollaba no leí acerca de los indices y cree muchos que prácticamente se repiten, por lo que necesito limpiarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo no puedo hacerlo desde la Cloud Console de Google, alguien sabe como hacerlo, uso java y xml para la configuración de los indices.

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes quitar los índices que no necesitas de tu archivo `xml`.

**importante**: Si no sabes si un indice se utiliza, no lo quites. No es posible para dar marcha atrás a esta operación.

Necesitas usar el comando `vacuum-indexes`.

Para `xml`, puedes usar `appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes <el-directorio-de-tu-aplicación>` o si usas Maven puedes utilizar `maven mvn:vacuum_indexes`.

Para más información, te recomiendo leer [`cleanup-indexes`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/datastore/cleanup-indexes). (Este comando es solo para `yaml`, pero los conceptos son similares).

Comment: No he usado los archivos yaml, en donde se agregan y como se ingresa el comando ? no hay manera de inyectar el delete por medio de datastore-indexes.xml ?

Comment: ¿los indices que quieres esta en su datastore-indexes.xml? No hay un "delete" comando, hay un comando para quitar los índices que no está en datastore-indexes.xml. ¿qual comando usas para insertar los índices?

Answer (score 2):

Una opción muy simple y también válida es utilizar **gcloud**.

> gcloud preview datastore cleanup-indexes ~/app/index.yaml

[cleanup-indexes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/datastore/cleanup-indexes)

también puedes reconstruir rápidamente por este medio, [create-indexes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/datastore/create-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

Estos indices se definen de [manera manual](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig), Si no creaste este archivo seguramente se creo de manera automática, corriendo consultas en el ambiente de desarrollo.

El archivo automático se encuentra en `WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml`, pero deberías encontrar el archivo definitivo en `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml`, este ultimo es el que deberías limpiar para que se eliminen los indices en el servidor.